# Can JS or Jquery be used in jasper reports input form section?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jasper reports and am now pretty comfortable using it. I use it on Ubuntu 12.04.
 I have to ask the user for inputs based on his previous inputs. 
 Ex : if the user selects A in a radio button I want the next radio button to ask for A1,A2 or A3. Similarly if he selects B the next radio should be B1,B2,B3.
I presume I will be able achieve it if there is some way to use JS or Jquery for the inputs.
Or is there a better solution to the problem??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Cascading Input controls
http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide-v52/cascading-input-controls

Comment: Thats pretty much what i was looking for.
Thanks :)